# Layout update customer account create not working

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layout-update

I'm trying to set the page template to 2columns-left.phtml for the account creation page in local.xml

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

It's however not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: do it in your existing theme and clear your cache .

Answer (score 1):

please check properly your local.xml file goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

check spaces.if spaces are their remove it.otherwise it will work.clear the cache

Comment: I copied your code and checked for spaces. Not working just yet. Any other ideas?